# select2 attribute "data-init-text"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I would like to populate a select, but do not have the associated description. 
Only have value.

I am using (select2):

```
$( '#element' ).attr( "data-init-text", "" ).val( value ).change();
```

but does not work because I have no description

I'm using a hidden input as an ajax call.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to do? Maybe set up a Fiddle? (jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the text (which you call the description) for the id (which you call the value). Since you are using ajax for the Select2 data, you could use an ajax call to get the text for an id.

You would supply an `initSelection` function that makes the ajax call. It might look something like this:

```
initSelection: function(element, callback) {
    var id= $(element).val();
    if (id) {
        $.ajax('/this/is/the/url/', {
            data: { id: id },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) { callback(data); } });
    }
}
```

In this case the ajax call passes the "id" parameter and is expected to return json that looks like this:

```
{ id: 'the_passed_in_id', text: 'the_text_for_the_id' }
```

[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n9MQ4/)

Answer (score 1):

Just create your normal select:

```
<select id='myId'>

 <option value='val1'>Option 1<option>

 <option value='val2'>Option 2<option>

</select>
```

$('#myId').select2();

That how you create a select2.

If you want to select an option:

$('#myId').select2('val', 'val2');

In this case Option 2 is selected.

Comment: Thansk, but I've used this solution but does not work. I'm using a hidden input as an ajax call.